# in javascript onmouseout, how to make work if cursor outside block?

Tags: javascript, mouseevent

have a menu item which displays a modal div.  wish the created div to close automatically whenever the user moves his cursor *out* of it, but when the modal div is created originally the cursor *is* out of it, so the cursor first needs to move inside of it.

when I log to the console the `onmouseout` trigger being fired, where both `e.target` and `e.currentTarget` are the div itself, the event fires *twice*, first on *entering* the div and then on *leaving* the div.

first, this does not make sense to me - why is the happening?  second, is there is a standard logic to use here?

---

all html is generated
here is some code which creates the modal and attached the `mouseout` trigger

```
// code creates the modal div from the menu
get:    function( e ) {
        util.popup( E.h4( "Maintenance Menu:" ),
           E.ul(  E.a( '#', maintenance.users, 'Users (Logins)' ),
                  E.a( '#', maintenance.employees, 'Employees' ),
                  E.a( '#', maintenance.skills, 'Skill Types' ),
                  E.a( '#', maintenance.etps, 'Expense Types' ),
                  E.a( '#', maintenance.menus, 'Menu Items' ) ),
            E.div(  E.button( maintenance.done, "s.width:90%", "Finished" ) ) );
         util.popup_dom().addEventListener( 'mouseout',util.popout() );
        },
```

`popup()` creates the modal and places it in BODY, `popout()` removes it.

---

solution (as per first answer - thanks!) using `mouseover` to set `mouseout`:

```
:
util.popup(...);
var outSet = false;  // whether mouseout trigger has been set
util.popup_dom().addEventListener( 'mouseover',function(e) {
   if( !outSet ) {
      setTimeout( function() { 
         util.popup_dom().addEventListener('mouseout',function(e){util.popout();} ),
         200 );
      outSet = true;
    }
} );
```

Comment: Share the HTML, and tell us how you want it to be before the `mouseout` and after it.

Comment: @Shef - here is the code snippet - don't know that it's what you were after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could only register the `onmouseout` listener `onmouseover`:

```
var closeModalDiv = function () { ... };

addEventListener(modalDiv, 'mouseover', function () {
    addEventListener(modalDiv, 'mouseout', closeModalDiv);
});
```

(This assumes you're using a custom, cross-browser event method named `addEventListener`; you'll have to adjust this to however it is you're registering events.)

Comment: I thought the `mouseover` event fired repeatedly.  _and_ afaik there is no way to pull or otherwise know of an existent trigger

Comment: 1. If you're using a decent cross-browser event method, it's not going to add the same function to the same element for the same event more than once. 2. If you didn't use an anonymous function, you *could* remove the `mouseover` listener after it was executed once.

Comment: followed your advice, but added a couple of things: a flag as to whether `mouseout` trigger had been added, to keep it from being reset, and adding the trigger 20ms after the `mouseover` to keep it from firing too soon. - thanks!

Comment: using `addEventListener` - this will not add listener function more than one time?

Comment: The W3C method known as `addEventListener` doesn't add duplicate functions. However, IE6-8 uses `attachEvent`, which *will* add the same function more than once. That's why you need a wrapper function that normalizes the two event models (read: fixes IE). Because I'm lazy, I suggest you just use jQuery's `bind` or `mouseover` methods.